# Select query to get a different representation of data of a table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as shown bellow is namely "source".

```
LoadNo | CostType | CostTotal | CostRate
-------+----------+-----------+---------
   100 | LHS      |      1000 |        4
   100 | FS       |      2000 |        3
   100 | STP      |      3000 |        5
   200 | LHS      |      4000 |        1
   200 | FS       |      1200 |        5
   200 | STP      |      3200 |        2
```

In this table, there are three CostType namely LHS, FS and STP. Now for each LoadNo, it will have all three CostType and for each CostType it will have CostTotal and CostRate (say for LoadNo 100 in the table it has all three CostTypes LHS, FS and STP as well as CostTotal and CostRate for each CostType). Now I'm trying to query on this table that I can retrieve output like bellow table

```
LoadNo | LHSCost | FSCost | STPCost | LHSRate | FSRate | STPRate 
-------+---------+--------+---------+---------+--------+---------
   100 |    1000 |   2000 |    3000 |       4 |      3 |       5 
   200 |    4000 |   1200 |    3200 |       1 |      5 |       2
```

In this o/p table loadNo is same as the source table but here CostType of source table (LHS, FS, STP and for each CostType has CostTotal and CostRate) are the become column combined with CostTotal and CostRate. So now columns are LHSCost, LHSRate, FSCost etc. So, please do help me to find a query/sp to get such output.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17943169/group-characters-of-varchar-field) is a link using recursive CTE's

Comment: @Lost that will be nuking a mosquito

Comment: @Serpiton thanks for letting me know, might need to go change an SP i did a while back :), so I am right in believing PIVOT is better performance wise ?

Comment: @Lost probably not, but the split and join was already taken :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it is using a `PIVOT`

```
Select LoadNo
     , LHSCost, FSCost, STPCost
     , LHSRate, FSRate, STPRate
From   (Select LoadNo
             , CostType + 'Cost' Type
             , CostTotal Value
        From   Table1
        UNION ALL
        Select LoadNo
             , CostType + 'Rate' Type
             , CostRate Value
        From   Table1) d
        PIVOT (AVG(Value) For Type IN (LHSCost, FSCost, STPCost
                                     , LHSRate, FSRate, STPRate)) pvt
```

Or you can fake it using aggregation

```
Select LoadNo
     , LHSCost = SUM(Case When CostType = 'LHS' Then CostTotal Else 0 End)
     , FSCost  = SUM(Case When CostType = 'FS'  Then CostTotal Else 0 End)
     , STPCost = SUM(Case When CostType = 'STP' Then CostTotal Else 0 End)
     , LHSRate = SUM(Case When CostType = 'LHS' Then CostRate  Else 0 End)
     , FSRate  = SUM(Case When CostType = 'FS'  Then CostRate  Else 0 End)
     , STPRate = SUM(Case When CostType = 'STP' Then CostRate  Else 0 End)
From   Table1
Group By LoadNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is waht you are looking for,

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(LoadNo int,CostType Char(4),CostTotal Int,CostRate int)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(100,'LHS',1000,4),(100,'FS',2000,3),
(100,'STP',3000,5),(200,'LHS',4000,1),
(200,'FS',1200,5),(200,'STP',3200,2)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

[image]

```
SELECT  LHS.LoadNo,
        LHS.CostTotal LHSCost,
        FS.CostTotal FSCost,
        STP.CostTotal STPCost,
        LHS.CostRate LHSRate,
        FS.CostRate FSRate,
        STP.CostRate CRate
FROM    (
        SELECT  LoadNo,
                MAX(CostTotal) CostTotal,
                MAX(CostRate) CostRate 
        FROM    @t 
        WHERE   CostType = 'LHS'
        GROUP BY LoadNo) LHS
JOIN    (
        SELECT  LoadNo,
                MAX(CostTotal) CostTotal,
                MAX(CostRate) CostRate 
        FROM    @t 
        WHERE   CostType = 'FS'
        GROUP BY LoadNo) FS ON LHS.LoadNo = FS.LoadNo
JOIN    (
        SELECT  LoadNo,
                MAX(CostTotal) CostTotal,
                MAX(CostRate) CostRate 
        FROM    @t 
        WHERE   CostType = 'STP'
        GROUP BY LoadNo) STP ON LHS.LoadNo = STP.LoadNo
```

[image]

Comment: The `GROUP BY` are not really needed